# Can you give me an example of comm.FSKModulator along with it's step function?

Tags: matlab

Can you tell me how to use PSKModulator with it's step function. I was able to solve comm.PSKModulator usage like this:

```
>> H=comm.FSKModulator('ModulationOrder',2,'BitInput',false,'SymbolMapping','Binary','FrequencySeparation',10);
```

but when I try to run Step function that takes H and X as arguments (X is digital values that I would like to encode in H) I get an error.

```
>> X=[0 1];
>> Y=step(H,X);
```

Error:
**Error using FSKModulator/step
Multichannel operation is not supported.**

I looked through Internet but there is no much of examples as this functions are very fresh.
do you know how to set up this?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Each column is treated as a different channel by this object. You need to send a column vector as input to the step method. In your code try using Y = step(H,X.') or change X to X = [0; 1];.